# How do I log out in the Google Drive iOS API?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm using Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/intro) to integrate Drive's functionalities in an app of my own, but I cannot find a way that allows me to log out of my google account from within the app.

Is there anything I can call to logout, or am I supposed to stay logged in until I uninstall the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more attempts, I may have found the solution:

In viewDidLoad, the Drive API service is initialized this way (taken from the aforementioned guide):

```
// Initialize the Drive API service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available.
self.service = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
self.service.authorizer =
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                      clientID:kClientID
                                                  clientSecret:nil];
```

So to logout, it should be enough to remove the authorization from the keychain:

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];
```

I just tried this out and it seems to be working. After this call, if I try to get back in the View, I'm prompted again for my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume clearing the cookies would do it. For example:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

[**NSHTTPCookieStorage Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Swift 2.2:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.removeAuthFromKeychainForName(kKeychainItemName)
```